# Sync multiple process traces for chrome://tracing

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, trace

I have multiple process producing traces in separate files, so I want to sync them to display on a single timeline. Let's say I have 2 files.

agent_service_trace.json:

```
{"traceEvents":[
  {"cat":"AgentService","pid":6876,"tid":6868,"ts":0,"ph":"X","name":"wWinMain","args":{},"dur":448701329},
  {"cat":"","pid":6876,"tid":6868,"ts":3,"ph":"M","name":"process_name","args":{"name":"AgentService"}},
  {"cat":"","pid":6876,"tid":6868,"ts":20,"ph":"M","name":"thread_name","args":{"name":"Main thread"}}
]}
```

agent_host_trace.json:

```
{"traceEvents":[
  {"cat":"AgentHost","pid":6564,"tid":6440,"ts":0,"ph":"X","name":"wWinMain","args":{},"dur":448701329},
  {"cat":"","pid":6564,"tid":6440,"ts":5,"ph":"M","name":"process_name","args":{"name":"AgentHost"}},
  {"cat":"","pid":6564,"tid":6440,"ts":10,"ph":"M","name":"thread_name","args":{"name":"Main host"}}
]}
```

They are started with slight difference in time, from few seconds up to few minutes. When I'm combining them one by one, since `ts` arg is time from the beginning of process tracing, they looks like were started at the same point in time.

From the [tracing](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CvAClvFfyA5R-PhYUmn5OOQtYMH4h6I0nSsKchNAySU/preview#) documentation and [clock sync](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1RPg7O8lHhYFYQA41OWKEYvD81PV6D1KWFv062k0cWhw/edit) addition especially, I'v found that Clock Sync event was created to handle multiple trace logs produced by different tracing agents and synchronize their clock domains. But as I know `chrome://tracing` doesn't support multiple files at time. The thing I'v tried so far, were adding clock_sync to events:

```
{"traceEvents":[
  {"ts":0,"ph":"c","name":"clock_sync","args":{"sync_id":"guid0","sync_ts":0}},
  {"cat":"AgentService","pid":6876,"tid":6868,"ts":0,"ph":"X","name":"wWinMain","args":{},"dur":448701329},
  {"cat":"","pid":6876,"tid":6868,"ts":3,"ph":"M","name":"process_name","args":{"name":"AgentService"}},
  {"cat":"","pid":6876,"tid":6868,"ts":20,"ph":"M","name":"thread_name","args":{"name":"Main thread"}},
  {"ts":0,"ph":"c","name":"clock_sync","args":{"sync_id":"guid1","sync_ts":30000}},
  {"cat":"AgentHost","pid":6564,"tid":6440,"ts":0,"ph":"X","name":"wWinMain","args":{},"dur":448701329},
  {"cat":"","pid":6564,"tid":6440,"ts":5,"ph":"M","name":"process_name","args":{"name":"AgentHost"}},
  {"cat":"","pid":6564,"tid":6440,"ts":10,"ph":"M","name":"thread_name","args":{"name":"Main host"}}
]}
```

I really don't know how this supposed to work, I'v tried to add `sync_id` as arg to events, also tried add `pid` as arg to `clock_sync` event. All of mine manipulations had no effect. I though there must be a link inbetween events and `clock_sync`'s `sync_id`, but unable to find any info on this. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I am also looking forward to an answer to this question. In the meantime, I made a custom python script to merge multiple tracefiles.

Comment: Hey @sbabbi. How do you sink multiple files? Do you using custom timepoint entrance? I'm looking forward to write custom utility, but I don't see any other way except using custom system time label.

Comment: I use the `clock_sync` events to figure out how much i should shift the `ts` entry (for a given tracefile). Then shift all the `ts` and merge everything in one json (does not need to be sorted by time apparently).